# How to validate sap.m.DatePicker selection against a dynamic minimum date?

Tags: validation, sapui5

Normal way to validate `sap.m.DatePicker` input looks like this:

```
new sap.m.DatePicker({
    value : {
        path : "someModel>/SomeDate",
        type :  new sap.ui.model.type.Date({}, {
            minimum : new Date()
        })
    }
})
```

I have the problem, that the "minimum" date will depend on different other parameters.
Binding in a type seems not working (or I do something wrong?).

I would be happy to have a function like this:

```
new sap.m.DatePicker({
    value : {
        path : "someModel>/SomeDate",
        type :  new sap.ui.model.type.Date({}, {
            minimum : "{someModel>/MinimumDate}"
        })
    }
})
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this?
I prefer to avoid the usage of id's to grab for a control in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build the following solution. Maybe there is a better way?

Definition of data type:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.CallbackDateType");

sap.ui.model.type.Date.extend("my.CallbackDateType", {
    constructor : function () {
        sap.ui.model.type.Date.apply(this, arguments);
        this.sName = "CallbackDateType";
    },

    validateValue : function(oValue) {
        var that = this;
        if (that.oConstraints.callback!==undefined) {
            that.oConstraints.callback[0].call(that.oConstraints.callback[1], that);
        }
        return sap.ui.model.type.Date.prototype.validateValue.call(this, oValue);
    }
});
```

Use like this:

```
new sap.m.DatePicker({
    value : {
        path : "model>/Date",
        type : new my.CallbackDateType({}, {
            minimum : new Date(),
            callback : [oController.getMinimumDate, oController]
        })
    }
})
```